# iOS Mail Compose Animation

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

How do I create the mail compose controller animation? Where it shows the previous controller in the background. Like the screen shot below.  [image]

Comment: I just want to make the modal viewcontroller act like this.

Comment: Hey @user2762657, have you found a solution?

Comment: I never found the solution.